# Сказуемое в предложении "Дома никого нет"

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

К предложению "*Дома никого нет*" хочу написать следующее объяснение:

> Частица *нет*, имеющая функцию сказуемого в данном предложении, имеет
>   форму настоящего времени.

Так правильно? Мне не нравится, как звучит: *частица **нет** в настоящем времени*.
Частицы ведь не имеют грамматического времени. Что здесь неправильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Из словаря:**

**НЕТ II. в функц. сказ.** 1. кого-чего. Не имеется в наличии; отсутствует (противоп.: есть). Можно поговорить со Святославом Владимировичем? - Его нет дома. Небоскрёбов в Петербурге нет. Нет денег. Нет времени.

[нет | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82&all=x)

**Дома никого нет (не было/не будет).**

Это **безличное** предложение, слово *нет* в роли сказуемого.

Отрицательное слово ***нет*** многозначное, в частности оно может выступать в функции сказуемого, обозначая отсутствие чего-либо **в настоящем времени.** В прошлом и будущем времени то же значение имеют слова ***не было, не будет.***

**Примечание.** Другие грамматические функции слова *нет* (согласно словарю)  ― это  частица и  союз.

Comment: Именно так, НЕТ здесь отрицательное слово, иногда его называют  безличным отрицательным словом, а не частица. Частицей является в предложении Нет, не пойду.